# How to use both default and material theme for different ng-select in Angular 6

Tags: angular, sass

I need to use `ng-select` with a material theme on my page, and `ng-select` with a default theme on another page.

I tried this on the first page:

```
<ng-select
  class="material"
  [items]="choices"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  name="{{name}}"
  bindLabel="value">
</ng-select>
```

on the second page:

```
<ng-select
  class="default"
  [items]="choices"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  name="{{name}}"
  bindLabel="value">
</ng-select>
```

and style.scss

```
.material {
   @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme";
}
.default {
   @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme";
}
```

But the resulting style looks like a combination of both material and default themes.

Is there any way to use both themes by using classes like above? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `style.scss` has the following code, your `~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme` will load inside `.default` and `~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme` will load inside `.material`

```
.material {
   @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme";
}

.default {
   @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme";
}
```

So change your HTML code like this. Hope it will work.

- **First Page**

```
<div class="default">
  <ng-select
    [items]="choices"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    name="{{name}}"
    bindLabel="value">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

- **Second Page**

```
<div class='material'>
  <ng-select
    [items]="choices"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    name="{{name}}"
    bindLabel="value">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```